CarouselView with ScrollView inside not aligning correctly and displaying Vertical not Horizontal
In my .NET MAUI App, I have the following ContentPage.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ManageItemsHelpPageViewModel"
             x:Class="OptimizerApp.Pages.HelpPages.ManageItemsHelpPage"
             Title="{loc:Translate HelpTopic_ManageItems}"
             x:Name="This">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ManageItemsHelpPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BorderStyleView" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
                <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 10, 10, 10, 10" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image ZIndex="1" Source="help_page.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="End"/>

        <Grid ZIndex="2">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>

        <Grid ZIndex="3">
            <Border x:Name="HelpPageBorder" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" SizeChanged="HelpPageBorder_SizeChanged"/>

            <Grid RowDefinitions="*, Auto" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="15">
                <ScrollView Margin="0,0,0,25" Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=CarouselViewItemHeight}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                    <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Loop="False" IsBounceEnabled="False" IndicatorView="indicatorView" VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" />
                        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:CarouselItem">
                                <Grid x:Name="carouselViewGrid" RowDefinitions="0.4*, 0.6*" ColumnDefinitions="*" Background="Yellow" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFit" IsAnimationPlaying="True" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,0,0,25" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CarouselView>
                </ScrollView>

                <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" Grid.Row="1" IndicatorColor="LightGray" SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray" IndicatorsShape="Circle" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0, 0, 0, 25" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>

namespace OptimizerApp.Pages.HelpPages
{
    public partial class ManageItemsHelpPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CarouselViewItemHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CarouselViewItemHeight), typeof(double), typeof(ManageItemsHelpPage), 0.0);
        public static readonly BindableProperty CarouselViewItemWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CarouselViewItemWidth), typeof(double), typeof(ManageItemsHelpPage), 0.0);

        public double CarouselViewItemHeight
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(CarouselViewItemHeightProperty);
            set => SetValue(CarouselViewItemHeightProperty, value);
        }
        
        public double CarouselViewItemWidth
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(CarouselViewItemWidthProperty);
            set => SetValue(CarouselViewItemWidthProperty, value);
        }


        public ManageItemsHelpPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HelpPageBorder_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HelpPageBorder.Height > 0)
            {
                CarouselViewItemHeight = HelpPageBorder.Height - 180;
            }

            if (HelpPageBorder.Width > 0)
            {
                CarouselViewItemWidth = HelpPageBorder.Width;
            }
        }
    }
}



As can be seen, the CarouselView should be scrolled horizontally, but when I scroll my ScrollView, I can see the 2nd Image which is bound to it, shows somewhere underneath the 1st Image:
<CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" />
</CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

The most annoying part is, that yellow part (the Grid) does not really just Fill horizontally, but it also streches the ScrollView obviously horizontally.
I tried different things with layouts and also explicit WidthRequest based on the outside Border, but couldn't get what I wanted.
What I wanted to achieve was that I have the content of one CarouselView-Page scrollable if the space is not sufficient (e.g. in Landscape orientation). The Width whould be restricted to the width of the parent Border. The IndicatorView should be visible at the bottom. Therefore, I placed the ScrollView inside the Grid. And as I mentioned, I also was wondering why it does not scroll vertically anymore.
What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this here?
Want to achieve a layout like this: The yellow part should be





=========== Sample Project ==============
I prepared a demo app in https://github.com/MAUIoxo/CarouselViewExample that shows the problem on iOS. It also demonstrates the difference between iOS and Android.
The issue can be seen when you navigate from in the Flyout > Help > Manage Items Help Page

Based on your code, I created a demo on my side. But I can scroll through every item in CarouselView horizontally normally. To be honest, I don't quite understand what you mean, can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to implement?

I added two drawings of what I wanted to achieve. It should be scrollable vertically when in Landscape orientation. We can discuss if it is better that the Image is wider in full with. But basically, I think it would be good if it looked like this.
Currently, on iOS, it is not working with the CarouselView as the 2nd element is not on the right, but underneath!

If I added code HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=CarouselViewItemHeight}" for the ScrollView, the app would crash once trying to my device.  Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to test on our side?

@JessieZhang-MSFT - I am sorry for the delay. I prepared a demo app on github.com/MAUIoxo/CarouselViewExample also see the comment in my original post how to navigate to the page. Also see the difference between iOS and Android. Hope you can also reproduce your problem with the HeightRequest issue. The example shows that it is layouted strangely and that it does not allow to scroll horizontally but only shows the elements underneath (vertically). It wasn't possible with this example to have the image squared as in my example image above, which is also strange. Is there a way to fix this?

Is your code uploaded correctly? After downloading your code, I can't build it successfully on my side.

@JessieZhang-MSFT - I cloned a fresh copy of my repository and it worked perfectly without any problems. I use XCode 15.2 and on my Windows machine VS 2022 - Version 17.11.0 Preview 2.1 with iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17.2 simulator. What was the exact error message on your side, could you post? I was thinking if the Apple Provisioning Profile Information in the .csproj caused a conflict with your personal profile, so I uploaded a new version without this information in the .csproj - Please try with this. Also let me know what error message you get, so I could try to support.

On my visual studio of my Windows machine, the error was : Severity Code  Description Project File Line Suppression State Details Error CS1705 Assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Graphics' with identity 'Microsoft.Maui.Graphics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  CarouselViewExampleApp (net8.0-ios) .

This message tells me that there are differences in the referenced .NET libraries. One is trying to reference System.Runtime in Version 9.0.0 and the other one is referencing System.Runtime in Version 8.0.0. In my project, I still use .NET 8 and haven't used any .NET 9 previews so far. Could you please clean and restore your NuGet-Packages and see if this solves the issue? (dotnet nuget locals all --clear and dotnet restore)

I'll try on my side and get back to you as soon as possible.

Thanks - let me know in case you need more information :)

I tried the command you mentioned above, but the problem remains. My other apps work fine on my side.

I wonder why it says version 9.0.0 on your side for the System.Runtime. I am pretty sure, I did not work with this version and also still use the older 8.0.0 framework. I thought that cleaning your NuGet-Cache could help. Maybe check again in the VS Settings how to do and check in your Windows User Profile that it is really cleared. Other than that, I do not have an explanation why you are having a higher version than is used in my csproj, where I compile for iOS 8.  %userprofile%\.nuget\packages (delete all subfolders). But, it looks like your compilation uses a 9.0.0 reference.

If clearing your NuGet-Cache and restoring them again did not help, you might also try to reference the older version in the csproj explicitly by adding the following ItemGroup: <ItemGroup>   <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="8.0.0" /> </ItemGroup>. But actually, I would assume that the cleaning und restoring process of the NuGet-Cache should fix it

Follow the method you suggested to add that line of code to the .csproj file, and more error messages will appear after building the code.

Hhm, okay it was only a try with this line in the csproj. Which .NET Version(s) do you have installed? Maybe it is simply that you do not have net8 installed and it takes 9 automatically? (Just guessing). But, to come to a solution, you could also just take my XAML, Code-behind and ViewModel files for the ManageItemsHelpPage into your own project you startet testing with when you encountered the problems and responded to initial question. Just wanted to mention, that I use net8 for the compilation. My uploaded project does not use fancy things, so this should be no big deal, I guess

As I said, I think you do not have a .NET 8 SDK installed which should probably be used as the App from my Project should be compiled for net8 as specified in the csproj. Maybe to verify if you have the right SDK available you might also check with dotnet --list-sdks which you have available and gets used for the compilation

After executing the command dotnet --list-sdks, the result was: `8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` .

Interesting, as we both have the same - I have [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  8.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk. The next thing, I checked is if I can get rid of some dependencies that might not be used for this example. I removed the dependency for CommunityToolkit.Maui, CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics and Refractored.MvvmHelpers. Especially for the "CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.1" removal could have the right impact. If you like you could try it with the new project upload and see if this helps on your side. As I can compile my side, we have to move forward like that - sorry

Yes, we could build and deploy the app to our device with the latest code, but we could not find the CarouselView with ScrollView on the UI.

What do you mean? Did you navigate from the Flyout menu > Help > Manage Items Help Page to the actual Page with the problem ?

@JessieZhang-MSFT - Didn't hear from you in a while if you could see and reproduce my example or if you need more information?
